# A tensor is invariant under diffeomorphism.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, lie-derivative, ricci-flow

Consider $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian Manifold (compact).

For a smooth function $f(x,t): M \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,

It is known that we can induce a one parameter group of diffeomorphism such that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi_t(x) = \nabla f (t, \phi_t (x)) $$
And $$\phi_0(x)=x$$

I want to show the trace free part of hessian of $f$ ,i.e. $$\nabla \nabla f -\frac{1}{2}\Delta f g$$ has length that is invariant under the diffeomorphism. Which means take $\phi_t^*g=\overline{g}$, $\phi_t^*\nabla=\overline{\nabla}$ , we have
$$|\nabla \nabla f -\frac{1}{2}\Delta f g|^2=|\overline{\nabla}\overline{ \nabla} f -\frac{1}{2}\overline{\Delta} f \overline{g}|^2 $$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $\nabla$ and $\Delta$ are intrinsic, doesn't that mean $\nabla \nabla f - \frac{1}{2}\Delta f g$ is intrinsic?

Comment: Yes, but is $\phi_t$ an isometry?(I don't know how to show it), or is there something I overlooked and can prove the result together with intrinsic property?

Comment: You should not expect $\phi_t$ to be an isometry in general. If a Killing vector field is the gradient of a function, then it must be parallel and the function harmonic. (Also, you probably meant to write $\phi_0(x)=x$ instead of $\phi_t(x)=x$.)

Comment: You are right, i will edit it. And I doubt gradf is a killing vector field.

Comment: @Kakashi I want to ask what can i do if it is intrinsic